# Sqlite error on different Machine with Swift

Tags: macos, swift, sqlite, sqlite.swift

I have made an app that has to access a database frequently. The app is Programed in swift and for the database access i use the framework SQLITE.swift from stephencelis. 
Everything works finde but when I install the Program on another machine with osx 10.9.4 I get the following error.

> dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _sqlite3_close_v2
>     Referenced from: /Applications/timeBro.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/SQLite.framework/Versions/A/SQLite
>     Expected in: /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib

Any Ideas how this can be handled? Should I add some requirements to the pkg I use?

Comment: Hm. Are you on the `swift-2` branch? We may need to change the `sqlite_close_v2` to use `sqlite_close` for compatibility with older systems (right now the deployment target is 10.10). I'll update the source accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! Yes I am in the swift-2 branch. As I said everything works fine with the actual version. I change the sqlite_close_v2 to sqlite_close. now it also works with older systems. Hope that cause any problems :)

Comment: I meant i hope it doesnt cause any problems :)

Comment: It shouldn't! I've also updated the `swift-2` branch to use `sqlite_close`.